# Adding a new row dynamically using a button

Tags: android, list, listview, baseadapter, android-adapter

I am trying to add rows in a list view when a button is clicked , but my application is getting crashed everytime .
Here is my code :

```
public class MTCRichGraphicsActivity extends Activity {
int ELEMENT_COUNT = 3;
int position=0;
Button bAddView;
String[] elements = new String[ELEMENT_COUNT];

int r =0 ;   


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bAddView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewEvent);
   final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3d);
    bAddView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.bNewEvent :
                for (int i = 0; i< ELEMENT_COUNT; i++) {
                    elements[i] = String.valueOf(i);
                }
                final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MTCRichGraphicsActivity.this,elements);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //list.setScrollY(currentPosition);
                //list.setTranslationY(currentPosition);
                list.setDivider( null ); 
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                ELEMENT_COUNT = ELEMENT_COUNT + 3;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Here I want to add 3 rows everytime a button(i.e. bNewEvent) is clicked , so I am incrementing ELEMENT_COUNT by 3 everytime. It works fine for first time , but when I press button second time it crashes.

Here is my adapter class :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final String[] mItems;
TextView t;
ViewHolder holder;
public MyAdapter(Activity c,String[] objects) {
    mInflater = c.getLayoutInflater();
    mItems = objects;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mItems.length;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView t;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem2, parent,false);
}
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
    holder.t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    holder.t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    holder.t4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    holder.t1.setText("Title"+position);
    position = position + 3;

    //((ImageView)convertView).setTextAlignment(1);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mItems[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show us your logcat?

Comment: use a collection class instead of array like List
you cannot increase the size of an array in runtime its immutable

Comment: @Premsuraj is right. you have to use arraylist instead of array,because arraylist don't required to initialized number of elements on it.

Comment: In logcat it was showing out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

you can't use an array like this..

```
String[] elements = new String[ELEMENT_COUNT];
```

causes the array to have the same number of elements as the initial value of ELEMENT_COUNT, you can't then just increment ELEMENT_COUNT by 3 and try

```
        for (int i = 0; i< ELEMENT_COUNT; i++) {
            elements[i] = String.valueOf(i);
        }
```

as the array only contains as many elements are initially defined. You need to change 'elements' to an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<string> elements;
```

Answer (score 0):

U define

```
int ELEMENT_COUNT = 3;
String[] elements = new String[ELEMENT_COUNT];
```

But u can't Resize Array

```
 for (int i = 0; i< ELEMENT_COUNT; i++) {
                elements[i] = String.valueOf(i);
            }
```

this So u got Exception

Change Array To List

Like

```
List<String> element =new ArrayList<String>();



   for (int i = 0; i< ELEMENT_COUNT; i++) {
                element.add("String.valueOf(i)")
            }
```

and Change Adapter also Like This